# Set object in different method

Tags: java, object, methods, jframe

Hi i need help with this code.
I really need help...

```
    package Window;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Window
{
    public static void build()
    {
        //Create Elements
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton send = new JButton();
        JTextArea dialog = new JTextArea();
        JTextArea input = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(
                dialog,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
        );
        send.setLocation(505,520);
        send.setSize(80,20);
        send.setBackground(Color.green);
        send.setText("Send");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(590, 600);
        frame.setTitle("Bot");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBackground(Color.green);
        dialog.setLocation(5, 5);
        dialog.setSize(575,510);
        input.setLocation(15, 520);
        input.setSize(490,25);
        frame.add(send);
        frame.add(dialog);
        frame.add(input);
        frame.add(scroll);
    }
    void show()
    {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to set the frame visible from a separate method. 
 But it cant find the frame object.

Is there any way to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the `show()` method know what to set visible.

Right now, you're defining the `JFrame` variable only for the scope of your `build()` method (so it cannot be accessed from other methods directly).

If this is your GUI class, you can make the `JFrame` a class variable. Like this:

```
public class Window {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
.
.
```

Or you can just define it and create the actual `JFrame` in your `build()` method:

```
public class Window {
JFrame frame;

public static void build(){
 frame = new JFrame();
 .
 .
```

Now you will be able to access the `frame` variable in your `show()` method. If you want to access it in a different class' method for example, you can just pass the `frame` object as an argument. Like so: `objectOfDifferentClass.myMethod(frame);` with the method in this class being defined as `myMethod(JFrame frame){...}`

[You can read more about variable scopes here.](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)